# Using generic and interface constraint : Can you explain the error on this code

Tags: c#

I get the following error :

> Error CS0311  The type 'ConsoleApp1.Diesel' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Car'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ConsoleApp1.Diesel' to 'ConsoleApp1.Fuel'.   ConsoleApp1

Why can't I constraint with the generic and the interface ?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public interface IVehicle
    {
        void StartEngine();
    }

    public abstract class Fuel
    { }

    public class Diesel : Fuel
    { }

    public class Engine<F>
    {    
        public void Start()
        { }

        private void TransformFuelToEnergy()
        { }
    }    

    public class Car<T> where T : Fuel, IVehicle
    {
        private Engine<T> engine;

        public void Start()
        {
            engine.Start();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car<Diesel> myCar;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its because your diesel is NOT derived from Fuel.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. That being said, `Diesel` does not derive from `Fuel`.

Comment: @daremachine: yeah I know, it's because I am not allowed to post the real code. I forgot the inheritance but it does not solve the error.

Comment: @olleo: Read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your class `Diesel` needs to inherit from `Fuel`:

```
public class Diesel : Fuel { }
```

Next, your `Engine<F>` should have a constraint where `F` is some type of `Fuel`:

```
public class Engine<F> where F : Fuel
{
    public void Start()
    { }

    private void TransformFuelToEnergy()
    { }
}
```

Finally, your `Car<T>` should implement `IVehicle` and include a constraint for `Fuel`:

```
public class Car<T> : IVehicle where T : Fuel
{
    private Engine<T> engine = new Engine<T>();

    public void StartEngine()
    {
        engine.Start();
    }
}
```

Your `Car<T>` class then provides the `StartEngine` method to satisfy the interface, which works on the private variable `Engine<T>` (which needs to be initialized).

Answer (score 1):

You have constrained the `Car<T>` class with a `where` statement saying that T must be either `Fuel` or `IVehicle`. The `Diesel` class is neither `Fuel` nor `IVehicle`, which leads to your compiler error.

I guess you want to have `Diesel` be a `Fuel`, in which case you can define it like this:

```
public class Diesel : Fuel { }
```

Which should make your code compile just fine.

Comment: It's not the inheritance.

Comment: Yes it is. The answer you accepted even makes the same point as I did (he just goes a bit further than the original question and fixes your code a bit more).

Answer (score 0):

When you use

> where T : Fuel, IVehicle

Its requiring the class you pass in to implement from both the abstract class and interface.

```
public class Diesel : Fuel, IVehicle
{
    public void StartEngine()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```